# Avoiding duplicate text input validation in Java and Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, validation, spring-mvc

I am using AJAX controller to provide the object from the server side. User enters the input, and AJAX controller provides the object for that input request. I have a **complex validation logic** so I have written it in Java, and put it in the AJAX controller. It looks like this:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "api/user/{user}", produces = "application/json", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public @ResponseBody UserData execute(@PathVariable(value = "user") String user) {

    if(validator.isValid(user)) {
        return service.getUserData(user);
    } else {
        throw new ResourceNotFoundException(INVALID_USER_FORMAT);
    }
```

In Javascript, I call the AJAX controller like this:

```
// obtain user from text input
var user = $('#user_input').val();

$.getJSON("/api/user/"+user, function (data) {
    // ...
});
```

Now, I want to display **on the UI an error message** where the entered user in `'#user_input'` is invalid. And I want to use the validation logic from my controller, and not to have duplicated validation logic also in Javascript.

What should I return from my AJAX controller when the validation doesn't succeed, and how to make use of that in Javascript, so that I can display something like "User format invalid"? What is the best practice?

Comment: just have status variable in  user data pojo make it as transient in the pojo if it is an hibernate entity and get data.status="success" in ajax and get it done .if failure set the variable to failure and return the appropriate message ...

Comment: @RamanaManoj The thing is that POJO comes from another service, I am not the one creating the POJO, but I am just retrieving external JSON, so I can't really add attributes on it.